# Android tensorflow set Max results

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The code for kotlin

```
val optionsBuilder =
  ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.builder()
    .setScoreThreshold(threshold)
    .setMaxResults(maxResults)
```

How to do the same in java

Refer:

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/66f60ebc3dd2e8527b7bbbb280fe0657d54f20f4/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder optionsBuilder =
    ObjectDetector.ObjectDetectorOptions.builder().
    setScoreThreshold(threshold).
    setMaxResults(maxResults);
```